# Значение слова — слит

Tags: значение-слов, значение

*Не все то злато, что блестит, -*

*Вот что мудрость говорит.*

*Жизнь продать иной спешит,*

*Чтобы лицезреть мой вид.*

*Червь в злаченом гробе скрыт.*

*Будь твой ум с отвагой слит,*

*Разум зрел, - хоть юн твой вид, -*

*Ты б не был холодом убит.*

*Так прощай, твой путь открыт*

(«Венецианский купец», Шекспир)

Будь твой ум с отвагой **слит** — «слит» здесь означает слитен, то есть, если бы ум слился с отвагой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Краткая форма от *слитый*. Как например в "Он был здесь как на ладони: простой, предсказуемый, *слит(ый)* в одно целое с коллективом".

По аналогии: *разбитый - разбит, выпитый - выпит* и т.п.